# How do I extract just the number from a named number (without the name)?

Tags: r, vector, named, lm

I am looking for just the value of the `B1(newx)` linear model coefficient, not the name. I just want the 0.5 value. I do not want the name "newx".

```
newx <- c(0.5,1.5,2.5)

newy <- c(2,3,4)

out <- lm(newy ~ newx)
```

`out` looks like:

```
Call:
lm(formula = newy ~ newx)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         newx  
       1.5         1.0
```

I arrived here.  But now I am stuck.

```
out$coefficients["newx"]

newx 
 
1.0
```

Comment: `as.numeric(out$coefficients["newx"])`

Comment: as.numeric is does work.  Maybe it is a low cost way to force out a number?

Comment: You can use the index number of `newx` (2) instead of the name like `out[[1]][[2]]`.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

For a single element like this, use `[[` rather than `[`. Compare:

```
coefficients(out)["newx"]
# newx 
#    1 

coefficients(out)[["newx"]]
# [1] 1
```

More generally, use `unname()`:

```
unname(coefficients(out)[c("newx", "(Intercept)")])
# [1] 1.0 1.5

head(unname(mtcars))
#                     NA NA  NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA
# Mazda RX4         21.0  6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1  4  4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1  4  4
# Datsun 710        22.8  4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1  4  1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  6 258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0  3  1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7  8 360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0  3  2
# Valiant           18.1  6 225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0  3  1

## etc.
```

Answer (score 10):

If the question is about removing names, another way is here

```
my_vec <- # some quantile function(returns named vector)
names(my_vec) <- NULL
my_vec
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy and rather direct way to do it is

```
as.numeric(out$coefficients["newx"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `broom` package:

```
broom::tidy(out)$estimate[1]
#1.5
```

Comment: A bit overkill, isn't it? Could you please shed some light on why this solution is more elegant/efficient than the accepted answer? I am asking from my utmost honest ignorance and not with a pedantic motif.