# Timing R code with Sys.time()

Tags: r, time, while-loop

I can run a piece of code for 5 or 10 seconds using the following code:

```
period <- 10  ## minimum time (in seconds) that the loop should run for
tm <- Sys.time()  ## starting data & time
while(Sys.time() - tm < period) print(Sys.time())
```

The code runs just fine for 5 or 10 seconds. But when I replace the period value by 60 for it to run for a minute, the code never stops. What is wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As soon as elapsed time exceeds 1 minute, the default unit changes from seconds to minutes. So you want to control the unit:

```
while (difftime(Sys.time(), tm, units = "secs")[[1]] < period)
```

From `?difftime`

```
 If ‘units = "auto"’, a suitable set of units is chosen, the
 largest possible (excluding ‘"weeks"’) in which all the absolute
 differences are greater than one.

 Subtraction of date-time objects gives an object of this class, by
 calling ‘difftime’ with ‘units = "auto"’.
```

Alternatively use `proc.time`, which measures various times ("user", "system", "elapsed") since you started your R session in seconds. We want "elapsed" time, i.e., the wall clock time, so we retrieve the 3rd value of `proc.time()`.

```
period <- 10
tm <- proc.time()[[3]]
while (proc.time()[[3]] - tm < period) print(proc.time())
```

If you are confused by the use of `[[1]]` and `[[3]]`, please consult:

- [How do I extract just the number from a named number (without the name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736719/4891738)
- [How to get a matrix element without the column name in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33976292/4891738)

---

Let me add some user-friendly reproducible examples. Your original code with `print` inside a loop is quite annoying as it prints thousands of lines onto the screen. I would use `Sys.sleep`.

```
test.Sys.time <- function(sleep_time_in_secs) {
  t1 <- Sys.time()
  Sys.sleep(sleep_time_in_secs)
  t2 <- Sys.time()
  ## units = "auto"
  print(t2 - t1)
  ## units = "secs"
  print(difftime(t2, t1, units = "secs"))
  ## use '[[1]]' for clean output
  print(difftime(t2, t1, units = "secs")[[1]])
  }

test.Sys.time(5)
#Time difference of 5.005247 secs
#Time difference of 5.005247 secs
#[1] 5.005247

test.Sys.time(65)
#Time difference of 1.084357 mins
#Time difference of 65.06141 secs
#[1] 65.06141
```

The "auto" units is very clever. If `sleep_time_in_secs = 3605` (more than an hour), the default unit will change to "hours".

Be careful with time units when using `Sys.time`, or you may be fooled in a benchmarking. Here is a perfect example: [Unexpected results in benchmark of read.csv / fread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496119/4891738). I had answered it with a now removed comment:

> You got a problem with time units. I see that `fread` is more than 20 times faster. If `fread` takes 4 seconds to read a file, `read.csv` takes 80 seconds = 1.33 minutes. Ignoring the units, `read.csv` is "faster".

Now let's test `proc.time`.

```
test.proc.time <- function(sleep_time_in_secs) {
  t1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(sleep_time_in_secs)
  t2 <- proc.time()
  ## print user, system, elapsed time
  print(t2 - t1)
  ## use '[[3]]' for clean output of elapsed time
  print((t2 - t1)[[3]])
  }

test.proc.time(5)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.000   0.000   5.005 
#[1] 5.005

test.proc.time(65)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.000   0.000  65.057 
#[1] 65.057
```

"user" time and "system" time are 0, because both CPU and the system kernel are idle.