# Creating a negative while, to let time pass before running next code

Tags: r, time, while-loop

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237158/timing-r-code-with-sys-time) on running some code for 10 seconds.

```
period <- 10  ## minimum time (in seconds) that the loop should run for
tm <- Sys.time()  ## starting data & time
while (difftime(Sys.time(), tm, units = "secs")[[1]] < period)
```

Instead I would like to NOT run anything for an hour, because of a download limit per hour.

```
period <- 60
tm <- Sys.time()  ## starting data & time
while (difftime(Sys.time(), tm, units = "minutes")[[1]] < period)
```

I have a feeling that I am not approaching this problem from the right angle, could someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: ?Sys.sleep 1234

Comment: so, you want R to be idle for an hour or R should not try to download something for at least an hour?

Comment: Does this help? https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/insistently.html

Comment: @mnist, idle in this case

Comment: `Sys.sleep(60*60)` should keep your system idle for an hour.